# Phrase for when something only broken when you need it to work

Tags: phrase-requests

Consider this scenario:

> Your computer is broken, so you call tech support. When they arrive to fix the computer, the problem is no longer present and the computer works as intended. Shortly after they leave, the problem begins again.

In this example your computer is broken when you need it to work, and works when you need it to be broken. Is there a phrase that describes this? I know Murphy's Law comes close to describing it, but doesn't seem to fit very well.

Comment: See [Term or phrase describing action occuring when not watching](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/148497/term-or-phrase-describing-action-occuring-when-not-watching) and [Term or expression which best describes a problem that goes away when an expert attempts to diagnose it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/184625/term-or-expression-which-best-describes-a-problem-that-goes-away-when-an-expert)

Comment: One of the contexts for _a watched pot never boils_.